# Powershell creating new self signed certificate. Root CA Certificate: extendedKeyUsage MUST NOT be present.t

Tags: powershell, ssl, certificate

I am currently making a RootCA and a SAN cert using powershell. 
Now everything is working as it should only it seems soms browsers are pretty strict when it comes to trusting a certificate. I am currently getting one last error when running my certificate through a linter (Z-lint in this case).

zlint   ERROR   Root CA Certificate: extendedKeyUsage MUST NOT be present.t

Now the error is pretty obvious... extendedKeyUsage should not be present in my powershell command when creating my RootCA

However I only use -keyUsage in my command. I am not quite sure what I need to adjust to my command to remove the error.

```html
$rootCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -keyUsage KeyEncipherment,DigitalSignature,CrlSign,CertSign -Subject "CN=AgionRootCA, OU=supplied, O=supplied, C=supplied, L=supplied, S=supplied"  -TextExtension @("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.10={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2", "2.5.29.19={text}CA=true","2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.12.1")
```

After following ->

> When looking at the Microsoft Docs for the New-SelfSignedCertificate cmdlet it says the following about the -KeyUsage switch:
>
> Specifies the key usages set in the key usage extension of the certificate. 
>   The acceptable values for this parameter are:
>
> - CertSign
> - CRLSign
> - DataEncipherment
> - DecipherOnly
> - DigitalSignature
> - EncipherOnly
> - KeyAgreement
> - KeyEncipherment
> - None (default)
> - NonRepudiation
>
> The default value, None, indicates that this cmdlet does not include the KeyUsage
>   extension in the new certificate.
>   So it would seem like that if you want extendedKeyUsage to NOT be present you need to change -keyUsage KeyEncipherment,DigitalSignature,CrlSign,CertSign to -keyUsage None which would be default if you don't include the switch at all.

The error messages increased stating that I do need regular -KeyUsage, but not -extendedKeyUsage

Error messages:

> zlint  ERROR   Root and Subordinate CA certificate keyUsage extension's crlSign bit MUST be set
>   zlint   ERROR   Root CA Certificate: Bit positions for keyCertSign and cRLSign MUST be set.
>   zlint   ERROR   Root CA Certificate: extendedKeyUsage MUST NOT be present.t

Comment: `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.10` is "Application Certificate Policies", and the value specified looks an awful lot like TLS Server and TLS Client EKU. Try leaving it out.

Comment: Thx for the help Barton you pushed me in the right direction, I started looking at the OID and found the problem there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I managed to solve the problem.
In my Powershell command I had added the OID 2.5.29.37 at the end and apparently
OID 2.5.29.37 is ExtendedKeyUsage. Therefore I kept on getting that problem. Closed!

More information on this matter [Self signed certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps)